# DropDown Ag-Grid Communty

Tags: jakarta-ee, angular7, ag-grid

I'm trying to bind some simple data from a database to a dropdown when editing a row in the grid, but I can't seem to get it with AG-grid free version.

Comment: Hi Mohamed and welcome to SOF. Do you have any code of what you have so far?

Comment: If possible, could you please reproduce a demo on stackblitz?